# Postgres 9.0 doesn't start because of "Panic XX000: GIN metapage disappeared"

Tags: postgresql

I've googled this error and found that I shoud start postgres in single user mode with -P option and reindex, but that doesn't want work since the error "GIN metapage disappeared" is occuring and no prompt is showing up.

I don't have a backup of this database so I'm stuck....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, solution given for helping purpose.

After an improved search it appears that this error message has been noted as a bug on PostgresSQL site and marked resolved.
So I updated the postgres server from 9.0.4 to 9.0.18 (the last 9.0.X version) and then start server as usual, no more PANIC message, server is running as if nothing happened.

Comment: That's why the Postgres devs recommend to never skip a minor upgrade  "*The community considers not upgrading to be riskier than upgrading*": http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/